# How to write multiIndex-columns excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to export a multiIndex-column.

I read an excel file (`https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G6nE5wiNRf5sip22dQ8dfhuKgxzm4f8E`) and exported it with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df.to_excel('sample2.xlsx', index = False)
```

However, `sample2.xlsx` has different format as `sample.xlsx`.

For example, there are merged cells in `sample.xlsx` but not in `sample2.xlsx` and the blank cells in `sample.xlsx` become `Unnamed:xx`.

You can view `sample2.xlsx` [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y3XttQfOrbCPu2er7_Ho2bEzBYyuB2pz).

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: can you update the sample data as well so others can understand the format differences

Comment: The url of `sample2.xlsx` has been added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you working with xlsx files, openpyxl package will do the job.

```
import openpyxl
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
wb_obj.save('sample2.xlsx')
```

Further reading on [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Thanks, Divya. How to convert a pandas dataframe to openpyxl object to save it?

Comment: sorry, but why convert to openpyxl object to save when we can directly save pandas dataframe?

Comment: It is because saving with pandas cannot keep the multi-indexed columns structure.